Combining a multi line batch command with inline comments
I have a very long command line string and i want to comment some arguments/switches and describe what they do and what can be adjusted with them. the following simplified batch-file does not work, but its more or less what I want to do:
executable^
 -switch1=3^                   rem should be 3 or 5, three means xxx and 5 means yyy
 -argument1=some-file.txt^
 -file-format=csv^             rem output file format, supported are csv and xml
 -out=result                   rem written file, file extension is copied from file format


I've created a simple script to test the syntax of combining comments with the split command string but I could not find a working solution:
rem WORKS, no space after caret
echo aaa ^
bbb

rem does not work, space after caret
echo aaa ^ 
bbb

rem WORKS space in the next line
echo aaa ^
 bbb

echo(
echo and now with rem-comments
echo(

rem does not work
echo aaa ^rem comment
bbb

rem does not work
echo aaa ^&rem comment
bbb

rem does not work
echo aaa ^ rem comment
bbb

rem does not work
echo aaa ^ &rem comment
bbb

echo(
echo and with double-colon-comments
echo(

:: does not work
echo aaa ^:: comment
bbb

:: does not work
echo aaa ^&:: comment
bbb

:: does not work
echo aaa ^ :: comment
bbb

:: does not work
echo aaa ^ &:: comment
bbb

Any character after the caret seems to break it, so it might not be possible at all to have a inline-comment after a caret? Does someone has an idea/solution?

Nope - the caret is an escape character, which basically escapes the following linefeed (very condensed description). Anything after it ruins this effect. That a space (and/or certain other characters) works, is due to the way the parser recognizes and "translates" the line.

An off-topic hint: Read the DosTips forum topic: ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/ The usage of echo. results always in accessing the file system for searching for a file with name echo in the current directory. The dot at the end is removed automatically by the Windows file I/O functions. It is better to use echo/ or echo( to output an empty line which is done in this case without a file system access which makes the batch file more fail-safe and a little bit faster processed.

Thats good to know, thanks for the hint!

You can use percent comments.
They disappears completely from the line, so they don't interfere.
echo aaa ^%=     My first comment here =%
bbb^%=           Second comment        =%
ccc%=            My last comment       =%

It works because the parser tries to expand the comment as a variable, but if it can't find such a variable, it expands to an empty string.
Therefore you should start with %=, because variables can not be created with a starting equal sign.
It's important not to include colons into the comments, because they are treated as special variable modification operators and breaks the comment completely.
A percent comment can be used at nearly any position in the line.
echo aaa ^%= My comment here =%
bbb%= This comment is in front of the caret=%^
c%=This comment is inside the text =%cc


Thats a very interesting solution  Still not sure if I am going to (or should) use it for two reasons: a) syntax highlighting in npp ignores it (because its not a comment but an intentionally wrong variable declaration) b) if someone else in my company does not know that colons are forbidden in that notation it could cause trouble. And of course I dont know if I remember that colons are forbidden when I have to modify the batch file in the future

@Michael You are right. But I advise against using batch files in production at all (although I am ranked 2nd among the top users in the batch-file tag). The effort to write stable and error-free batch files is simply too high

I would not call it production directly (not delivered to customers), we use batch files for internal stuff like launchers for client/server java apps, openssl and ffmpeg stuff. those batch files are already existing, but its not fun to dig into openssl or ffmpeg when you haven't touched those files for a while. thats why i am looking for something to document switches/arguments in the batch file as close as possible to the actual argument...

I'll mark your answer as accepted, as it does what I asked for, but i'll use Mofi's suggestion for documentation as I think its easier to read.

Your original concept is wrong because the ^ end of line character must be placed at end of line...
I propose a different approach that have no problems with colons placed in the comments:
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set ^"\n=^
%don't remove%
^"

set "command="
for /F "delims=/" %%a in (^"

executable                                                                          !\n!
 -switch1^=3               // should be: 3 or 5, three means xxx and 5 means yyy    !\n!
 -argument1^=some-file.txt                                                          !\n!
 -file-format^=csv         // output file format, supported are: csv and xml        !\n!
 -out^=result              // written file, file extension is copied from file format

^") do set "command=!command! %%a"

%command%

In this method an "end of line" \n variable is created first and placed at end of each of the lines that comprise the command. Each line is processed via for /F command and used to assemble the final command. The "comment part" is separated via a slash that is included in the delims=/ part of the FOR /F command. You could also use an uppercase "R" as comment separator and separate the comments with REM commands.
The executed command is this:
executable   -switch1=3   -argument1=some-file.txt   -file-format=csv   -out=result

The only drawback with this method is that the equal signs must be ^= escaped because the parser remove they.

It is not possible to have commands like rem inside a command spread over multiple lines. The caret character ^ as escape character at the end of a line works only if there is next carriage return (ignored on reading the batch file automatically) and line feed. Even a trailing whitespace character like a normal space or horizontal tab would result in splitting up the long command line into two command lines and the execution of the executable would not work as expected. The Windows Command Processor uses a very old syntax which is not space/tab tolerant like modern script interpreters. For more information regarding processing of a command line or a batch file see: How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?
The solution is very simple. The long command line is written in the batch file as one long command line and the options are all explained in a block above which is ignored more or less on execution by using the command goto as demonstrated below.
goto RunExe
rem   -switch1=3 ......... should be 3 or 5, three means xxx and 5 means yyy
rem   -file-format=csv ... output file format, supported are csv and xml
rem   -out=result ........ written file, file extension is copied from file format
:RunExe
executable -switch1=3 -argument1=some-file.txt -file-format=csv


excellent readability () close to typical help/man pages. i see only one very small disadvantage as you have all switches and arguments twice, you have to keep the comment in sync when adjusting/tweaking the real command line... but of course, thats a human problem
